# How to test a pandas model created with OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have the following DataFrame:

| VIN | AutoMaker | Model | Version | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WAUAFK8P6BA166694 | AUDI | A3 | SPB 2.0T FSI | 2011 |
| WAUDFA8U3ER082870 | AUDI | Q3 | 2.0TFSI | 2014 |
| WAUAFK8P0CA014105 | AUDI | A3 | SPB 2.0T FSI | 2011 |

I want to predict the AutoMaker, Model, Version and Year columns based on the VIN number.

I've successfully created a model using the following code:

```
X_data = dataframe['VIN'].str.split(r"", expand=True).drop([0, 18], axis = 1)
x_data_encoded = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_data)
```

Then I used `.unique()` and LabelBinarizer in each label column to create a model like this:

```
split = train_test_split(x_data_encoded, modelLabels, versionLabels, yearLabels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
(trainX, testX, trainmodelY, testmodelY, trainversionY, testversionY, trainyearY, testyearY) = split

models = keras.Sequential()
models.add(keras.Input(shape=(171,)))
models.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
models.add(layers.Dense(len(dataframe.Modelo.unique()), activation = "softmax", name='modelo_output'))
models.add(layers.Dense(len(dataframe.Versao.unique()), activation = "softmax", name='versao_output'))
Inputs = keras.Input(trainX.shape[1], name="input_modelo")
Features = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(Inputs)
Outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(Features)
ModelsOutputs = layers.Dense(len(dataframe.Modelo.unique()), activation="softmax", name='modelOutput')(Features)
VersionsOutputs = layers.Dense(89, activation="softmax", name='versionsOutput')(Features)
model = keras.Model(inputs=Inputs, outputs=[ModelsOutputs, VersionsOutputs])

losses = {
    "modelOutput": "binary_crossentropy",
    "versionsOutput": "binary_crossentropy"
}

lossweights = {
    "modelOutput":1.0,
    "versionsOutput":1.0
}

metrics = {
    "modelOutput": "accuracy",
    "versionsOutput": "accuracy"
}

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=losses, loss_weights=lossweights, metrics=metrics)

ep = 50
bt = 512

history = model.fit(x=trainX,
      y={"modelOutput": trainmodelY,
         "versionsOutput": trainversionY},
                validation_data=(testX, 
                                 {"modelOutput": testmodelY,
                                  "versionsOutput": testversionY}),
                epochs=ep, batch_size=bt, verbose=1)
```

I've already tested with the test data, for example:

```
prediction = model.predict(testX[150])
predictedModel = np.argmax(prediction[0])
print(modelo_mask[predictedModel])
```

But I cant figure out how to simply pass a VIN string to the model. For example, given the string "WAUAFK8P0CA014105", how should I prepare it to pass into model.predict?

Comment: Don't do this: `OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_data)`. Instead, save your encoder, `encoder = OneHotEncoder(); x_data_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(X_data)`, then later you can re-use `encoder` to encode new test data?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for the answer. Can you give me an example on how to later use the `encoder` together with model.predict ?

Comment: Some thing like this: `x_test = encoder.transform([vin_num.str.split()[1:18]]); prediction=model.predict(x_test)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you. This compiles and runs without errors, but for some reason, the prediction gets me wrong results. During the training, it gets me an accuracy of 0.99.

Comment: i've used: `encoder.transform([list("WAUAFK8P0CA014105")])`. Is this right?

Comment: `list("WAUAFK8P0CA014105")` returns a list of individual characters. maybe you mean `encoder.transform(["WAUAFK8P0CA014105"])` ? or if it's supposed to be a nested list, `encoder.transform([["WAUAFK8P0CA014105"]])` ?